# Finding two dimensional critical point

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I'm reading an article about bi layered membranes which state that for the free energy function
$f(\theta) = \theta \ln \theta + (1-\theta)\ln(1-\theta) + \chi \theta (1-\theta)$

Where $\phi_i$ is the mole fraction of certain types of lipids in layer $i$ and $\chi$ is the energy of interaction between two lipids molecules composing the layer. The article states that a critical point exist at $\chi=2$ and $\theta=0.5$. Reading in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28thermodynamics%29), I concluded that removing the layers interaction part, I simply need to take the second and third derivative of the free energy of the membrane. How do I do this with the interactions? Where can I read about this?

Comment: Which article are you reading?

Answer (score 2):

> removing the layers interaction part, I simply need to take the second and third derivative of the free energy of the membrane

What do you mean by *“removing the interactions”*? The critical point is the point where the second and third derivatives of $f(\theta)$ are equal to zero. This gives directly the conditions you cited:

[image]